# problems using KbCheck and KbName (writing a matlab script)

Tags: matlab, keyboard, keypress

I am currently writing code for a study using matlab and psychtoolbox on a Ubuntu system.

I'm currently trying to write a code snippet where the subject presses either the up or down key in response to a task and then metadata is collected.

However, while my code works fine on my own pc it doesn't work in the lab.
It looks like this:

```
ListenChar(1)
while 1
    [keyIsDown, seconds, keyCode ] = KbCheck;
    if keyIsDown
        if keyCode(KbName('up'))
            disp('up key was pressed');
            break;
        end
        if keyCode(KbName('down'))
            disp('you pressed the down key');
            break;
        end
    end
end
```

I have also tried using just keyCode with numbers I got from here: https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes which didn't work either.
The Key Name 'up' I got from using KbName('KeyNamesLinux'). I also tried 'KP_Up' and 'UP_ARROW'.
When using 'space' (and using the space key respectively) everything works fine.

If anyone has an idea I'll be thankful for any input!

Best,
Anna

Comment: Can you not just print the keycode and see what it is?

Comment: That sounds good- how do I do that?

Comment: Um... `disp(keyCode)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked. In retrospect I see how it was a pretty silly question however I was at a loss :D